# Debugging WCF service hosted in IIS 6.0 using Visual Studio 2005

Tags: wcf, debugging, visual-studio-2005, iis-6

I've created a WCF service selecting 'WCF Service' in installed web site templates in VS2005. I've added a ASP.Net client for the service in the SAME solution. I published the WCF service in IIS 6.0 and configured it to run in .Net Framework 2.0.

I did an IISAPP in command prompt and identified the PID of the w3wp.exe process of my service application in IIS. I attached the debugger in VS to that process and started a new instance of the asp.net client project.

But i'm not able to step in to the service and the breakpoint is not enabled at all showing 'No symbols have been loaded'.

Any insights on this? Can i debug a WCF service hosted in IIS 6.0 using VS 2005 where the service and client resides under SAME solution?

Thank you

NLV

Comment: Please, share more details, configured Application Pools, publishing configuration (realease, debug, ...). Is the IIS on the same machine?

Comment: I'm just publishing it in debug mode. IIS is in the same machine. Created a new application pool with default configuration and assigned it to the site containing the service.